# How can I handle null value in this kind of situation in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, exception, plsql

I wrote code to get a batting average and on-base percentage. Problem is, whenever I skipped to insert a value, since it's a null value I only get an error message and the code returns nothing.

What I want to do is when I skip to insert a value, program automatically turns that empty value into 0 and make this code works.

For example:

```
PA : 595
Hit : 153
NIBB : 79
SC : 
SF : 3
```

and makes code return

```
BA : .298
Onbase: .388
```

This is my code:

```
set serveroutput ON

accept p_num1 prompt 'PA : '
accept p_num2 prompt 'Hit : '
accept p_num3 prompt 'NIBB : '
accept p_num4 prompt 'SC : '
accept p_num5 prompt 'SF : '

DECLARE
    v_pa number:=&p_num1;
    v_hit number:=&p_num2;
    v_nibb number:=&p_num3;
    v_sc number:=&p_num4;
    v_sf number:=&p_num5;
    v_ba number(4,3);
    v_ob number(4,3);
    

BEGIN
    v_ba := v_hit/(v_pa-v_nibb-v_sc-v_sf);
    v_ob := (v_hit+v_nibb)/(v_pa-v_sc);
    dbms_output.put_line('BA : ' || v_ba);
    dbms_output.put_line('OnBase : ' || v_ob);


    end;
/
```

I tried to use both exception and default, but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to include `NVL` function:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_pa    NUMBER := 595;
  3     v_hit   NUMBER := 153;
  4     v_nibb  NUMBER := 79;
  5     v_sc    NUMBER := NULL;
  6     v_sf    NUMBER := 3;
  7     v_ba    NUMBER (4, 3);
  8     v_ob    NUMBER (4, 3);
  9  BEGIN
 10     v_ba :=
 11        NVL (v_hit, 0) / (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_nibb, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0) - NVL (v_sf, 0));
 12     v_ob := (NVL (v_hit, 0) + NVL (v_nibb, 0)) / (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0));
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BA : ' || v_ba);
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('OnBase : ' || v_ob);
 15  END;
 16  /
BA : ,298
OnBase : ,39

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

That *works*, kind of. However, it wouldn't work if divisor evaluates to zero as you'd get ORA-01476 error. Handle it, somehow. For example, you could *detect* whether divisor is equal to zero and then divide by a very large number (and get 0 as the final result):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_pa      NUMBER := 0;
  3     v_hit     NUMBER := 153;
  4     v_nibb    NUMBER := 0;
  5     v_sc      NUMBER := NULL;
  6     v_sf      NUMBER := 0;
  7     v_ba      NUMBER (4, 3);
  8     v_ob      NUMBER (4, 3);
  9     --
 10     v_div_ba  NUMBER;
 11     v_div_ob  NUMBER;
 12  BEGIN
 13     v_div_ba := (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_nibb, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0) - NVL (v_sf, 0));
 14     v_div_ob := (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0));
 15     --
 16     v_ba := NVL (v_hit, 0) / CASE WHEN v_div_ba = 0 THEN 1E99 ELSE v_div_ba END;
 17     v_ob :=
 18        (NVL (v_hit, 0) + NVL (v_nibb, 0)) / CASE WHEN v_div_ob = 0 THEN 1E99 ELSE 0 END;
 19
 20     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BA : ' || v_ba);
 21     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('OnBase : ' || v_ob);
 22  END;
 23  /
BA : 0
OnBase : 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Or, you could include EXCEPTION handlers - two of them, enclosing `v_ba` and v_ob`calculations into its own`begin-exception-end` block:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_pa    NUMBER := 0;
  3     v_hit   NUMBER := 153;
  4     v_nibb  NUMBER := 0;
  5     v_sc    NUMBER := NULL;
  6     v_sf    NUMBER := 0;
  7     v_ba    NUMBER (4, 3);
  8     v_ob    NUMBER (4, 3);
  9  BEGIN
 10     BEGIN
 11        v_ba :=
 12             NVL (v_hit, 0)
 13           / (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_nibb, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0) - NVL (v_sf, 0));
 14     EXCEPTION
 15        WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE
 16        THEN
 17           v_ba := 0;
 18     END;
 19
 20     BEGIN
 21        v_ob := (NVL (v_hit, 0) + NVL (v_nibb, 0)) / (NVL (v_pa, 0) - NVL (v_sc, 0));
 22     EXCEPTION
 23        WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE
 24        THEN
 25           v_ob := 0;
 26     END;
 27
 28     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('BA : ' || v_ba);
 29     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('OnBase : ' || v_ob);
 30  END;
 31  /
BA : 0
OnBase : 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, quite a few options ... some more are also possible. Pick the one you find the most appropriate.